# Using SetInterval in node.js REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have the following javascript file:

```
function logMe() {
  for(var i=0; i < 4; i++) console.log(i);
}

setInterval(logMe(), 2000);
```

Then I open a node.js REPL with the command `node`.

I then load and evaluate my script with:

```
eval(fs.readFileSync('myScript.js').toString())
```

I get back the error:

```
TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function
    at exports.setInterval (timers.js:414:11)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:68), <anonymous>:5:1)
    at repl:1:1
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:346:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:545:10)
```

Is there a potential work around here if I want to use setInterval within the node REPL?

Comment: `setInterval(logMe, 2000)`, _without_ the `()`.

Comment: And FWIW, you should just do `require('./myScript')` instead of using `eval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, just a typo on your part.

```
setInterval(logMe, 2000);
```

You need to pass your function as a function rather than calling it.

Comment: That is not what I would call a typo. Maybe the OP didn't know what he was doing

Comment: @bugwheels94.  Ok, that doesn't change my answer. It could be a typo, or it could be ignorance. Either way my answer solves it.

Answer (score 2):

`logMe()` will exexute the function

where as in `setInterval` you need to pass the function

```
function logMe() {
  for(var i=0; i < 4; i++) console.log(i);
}

setInterval(logMe, 2000);
                 ^ no ()
```

---

```js
    function logMe() {
      for(var i=0; i < 4; i++) console.log(i);
    }
    
    setInterval(logMe, 2000);
```

---

```js
function logMe() {
  for(var i=0; i < 4; i++) console.log(i);
}

setInterval(logMe(), 2000);
```

---